# PCB design rule errors, but can't understand why

Tags: pcb-design, error, drc, ultiboard

I am trying to create a PCB using NI Ultiboard. My circuit is a SECPIC DC-DC converter and controlling the L1 current. This is my circuit:

[image: schematic diagram]

and I get this error:

```
Design rule error: Net "VOUT" close to net "3".
Design rule error: Net "3" close to net "VOUT".
```

[image: large area of PCB]

This is the area of the error (zoom of the second picture):

[image: small area of PCB]

I can't understand why I get this error, because in Multisim the circuit is working fine. Can anyone explain the cause for the error?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a hole there with a copper ring around it: The blue ring.

It is actually too close to the next pin.

Comment: ok how can i fix this problem  ?

Comment: remove the copper ring. (your question strikes me as a bit of strange, what did you expect?)

Comment: the thing is that I cant remove this copper ring , and tell you the truth I cant undestand why there is copper ring there in the first place , I have other SMD components and they dont have copper rings .   Why do I have this rings ? and I am new to the PCB thing so I am sorry if I ask base questions

Comment: you're the one who (accidentally) added the copper ring. I'm sorry, removing elements from your schematic is something you should be able by now.

Comment: I deleted the ring but for some reason it appears every time ...

Comment: Check the footprint of the component.

Comment: also make sure that you don't have a short length of trace on the bottom side. Then, the program *has* to insert a via. For example, the red arch at your `trans_driver` is a no-go. (there's a lot of problems with your layout, but addressing them all would lead too far)